# MYSQL prepare statements procedure which updates a variable number of columns of a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I need to create a stored procedure which uses prepared statements, whose purpose is to update a table. The thing is that I don't know beforehand which columns of the table will be updated. It can be one column, several or all of them. I created the procedure below but I ran into a problem I can't figure out:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `updateEntries`(  IN setcols varchar(200), 
                            IN column varchar(20), 
                            IN relation varchar(10), 
                            IN value varchar(15), 
                            IN setvalue varchar(100)
                         )
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE table SET ',setcols,' WHERE ', column,' ', relation,' ?');
SET @setvalue = setvalue;
SET @value = value;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @setvalue, @value;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I can easily call the procedure when I must update only one column, like this:
`call updateEntries('column = ?','id', '>', 2, 'new_value')`
because my `@sql` would then be: `UPDATE table SET column = ? WHERE id > ?;` `new_value` would be assigned to `@setvalue` and `2` would be assigned to `value` then everyting executed.

However, I can't figure out what should I do when there are multiple columns to update, since I need to store all these new values for each column into variables, which `EXECUTE` would use.
Is there a way to store all the new values into a single variable, maybe a string, and have my procedure pick the values from it? 
Or what options do I have?

Comment: Just curious- and it maybe a perfectly reasonable explanation- but wouldn't you know which columns would need updating?

Comment: nope, I can't know which column will be updated or how many of them

Comment: I meant "why wouldn't "

Comment: because, now, user1 may use the app which uses the procedure to update columns 2, 6 and 7. Later, user2 may use it to update only column 4. And so on and so forth. Since the procedure should work with just one table, I know what the columns' names may be. But I can't know exactly, for each instance, what columns will be updated

Comment: ? Are you aware of the VALUES option under `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax. Would that help at all?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to help, but definitely I'm going to try :)